# How to make loading time faster for permissions page in prestashop backend?

Tags: prestashop-1.5

Research on the question

I have tried following to make loading time faster for backend
1. clearing cache
2. changing the modified values in smarty.config.inc.php to default values instructed in offcial documentation of performance tuning
3. Restarting httpd server 
4. Restarting Mysqld server

All I got is, loading time now of back office is much faster than before for all other pages except the page "permissions" 
Whenever I try to navigate to permissions page it takes almost 250-300 seconds to load the page. I tried with different web browsers but got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions page may load slow if you have many modules installed and enabled. Try disabling few of them.